# How can I animate a strap attached to a buckle

Tags: animation

This is my first post here, so please be gentle if I forgot information or I have to ask a question twice ... :)
I am still trying to find my way around in Blender, but here I am at my limit:
I have a buckle mechanism, that I animated in Blender which worked just fine (please take a look at the attached video)
But I have to attach a strap to that buckle, which follows the movement of the opening buckle.
I tried to do this via parenting vertex of the strap in Edit mode to parts of the buckle.
I did this for either side, but:
a) as you can see in the video, the strap disregarded the parenting I did first on the other side.
b) the strap would also need to behave more like a cloth. In reality the strap is kind of a seatbelt material, so it is somewhat stiff, yet still flexible to a degree.

As for my model: the buckle is imported CAD data. Original files are STEP files. The data is triangulated.
The strap I created in Blender using a plane. I used a Solidify and a SubD modifier, not yet applied.
As for the behavement of the strap, I was considering using shape keys.
so my questions are:

1. how can I attach both sides of the strap to the buckle?
2. how can I create a somewhat more realistic movement/ behaviour of the strap?
   [image]
   [image]

[image]

Thanks a lot upfront ! This forum has helped me a ton getting into Blender, just by silently following and I think this is a great community !!

best
Fryday

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: it would help if you provide your blend file. If you don't want that, try to simplify your blend file and provide that so we can help you better. and....a person who made such an animation is NOT a noob....stop lying! ;)

Comment: Hello Ramos, sorry I tried to improve the post and added two gifs, which I think are necessary to understand the problem. Hope that is better now!

Comment: Hello Chris, thanks for your comment and kindness :) I have no problems and sharing the file, but how would I do that ?

Comment: just open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions -> paste the "url" you get into your question

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=q7l3d4Qs" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/q7l3d4Qs/)

Comment: You can attach the belt to the buckle with a pin group. Add the vertices of both ends of the belt to a vertex group and call it "Pin" or what you like. Then set this vertex group in the *Cloth* settings in *Shape > Pin Group*. This excludes the assigned vertices from the cloth sim and you can animate them. Have you considered using a rig for the animation?

Comment: sorry, it took me a couple of days to get back here!

Comment: I am thankful for your help, Blunder... this lead me into the right direction!